# Checking that a control exists or not in a cell where user has clicked in tablelayoutpanel

Tags: c#, user-controls, tablelayoutpanel

How can I check that the control exists on that cell where the user has clicked? Is there any kind of function of the tablelayoutpanel?
I just want to check that if the clicked cell HasControl then delete that control in that specific cell.

Comment: What if user clicks on control itself rather than panel's cell area?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a built in function for this, so you would have to find the cell position yourself:

```
void tlp_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
    int[] colWidths = tlp.GetColumnWidths();
    int[] rowHeights = tlp.GetRowHeights();
    int top = tlp.Parent.PointToScreen(tlp.Location).Y;
    for (int y = 0; y < rowHeights.Length; ++y) {
      int left = tlp.Parent.PointToScreen(tlp.Location).X;
      for (int x = 0; x < colWidths.Length; ++x) {
        if (new Rectangle(left, top, colWidths[x], rowHeights[y])
                          .Contains(MousePosition)) {
          Control c = tlp.GetControlFromPosition(x, y);
          if (c != null) {
            c.Dispose();
          }
        }
        left += colWidths[x];
      }
      top += rowHeights[y];
    }
  }
}
```

Do note that the functions `GetColumnWidths()` and `GetRowHeights()` are not visible from intellisense.  Also, if the user clicks on the control itself, this code won't fire.  You would have to handle the MouseDown event of the control in that cell.

Comment: But I have to check on a button click.. How can I do that?

Comment: I have created my own user control so I can not pass these arguments into that. Then How can I check that is it present of not?

Comment: @NosheenJaved Well, what button click?  What UserControl?  You are describing things I cannot see.  I can only provide an answer based on your question, and your question asked how to click on a cell to remove the control within that cell.  So if you need more help, please give me more information on what you are trying to do.  `tlp_MouseDown` is the MouseDown event of a TableLayoutPanel in my example.